Boundary сonditions specified in different domains
I am modeling mass transport phenomena involving convection and diffusion within a two-dimensional box. The box has a height ranging from 0 to h along the y-axis and is divided into two domains along the x-axis: domain 1 from d0 to d1, and domain 2 from d1 to d2.
The boundary conditions are:
enter image description here
Where, C(t,x,y) is the concentration and C^* is a constant nominal concentration. I am trying to use the following script to solve this problem in Wolfram Mathematica version 13.2, however I don’t know how to write the boundary conditions at the y-axis. I have used functions such as Piecewise, DirichletCondition, If, and WhenEvent to specify the different domains within the condition but many errors appears and the system does not solve.
eqns=D[C[t,x,y],t]==Piecewise[{{dif1*D[C[t,x,y],x,x]+dif1*D[D[t,x,y],y,y]-D[uy C[t,x,y],y],d0<=x<=d1},{dif2*D[C[t,x,y],x,x]+dif2*D[C[t,x,y],y,y],d1<x<=d2}}];

cond={C[0,x,y]==0,Derivative[0,1,0][C][t,d0,y]==0,Derivative[0,1,0][C][t,d2,y]==0, Derivative[0,0,1][C][t,x,0]==0,(* here should be specified the other boundary conditions*)};

sol=NDSolve[{eqns,cond},C,{t,0,ts},{x,d0,d2},{y,0,h},MaxSteps->Infinity,Method->{"MethodOfLines","DifferentiateBoundaryConditions"->False}];

Where, dif1 and dif2 are the diffusion coefficients ate domains 1 and 2 respectively, uy is the convection velocity at domain 1, and ts a constant time value. Could someone help me with this problem?
However I don’t know how to write the boundary conditions at the y-axis. I have used functions such as Piecewise, DirichletCondition, If, and WhenEvent to specify the different domains within the condition but many errors appears and the system does not solve.
